# How to deploy a local postgresql database of Ruby on rails app to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have been trying to deploy a local database which has some data into heroku. My app's name is myFirstBlog. But after deploying when I refresh my app, it says something went wrong. After so troubeshooting. I found out this:

Before exporting data into heroku database, I ran the command

```
heroku pg:info
```

And the output was:

```
Plan:Hobby-dev
Status:Available
Connections:1/20
PG Version: 9.4.1
Created: 2015-07-09 08:20 UTC
Data Size:6.6 MB
Tables: 3
Rows: 2/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

And after I exported data to heroku and ran the same command, output was:

```
Plan: Hobby-dev
Status: Available
Connections:1/20
PG Version:9.4.1
Created:2015-07-09 08:20 UTC
Data Size:6.5 MB
Tables:0
Rows: 0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:Unsupported
Rollback:Unsupported
```

The number of tables becomes 0 after export. Why is it happenning?
This is how I am exporting my local database's data to heroku:

```
PGPASSWORD="password" pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U aditya9509 myFirstBlog_development > backup.dump  //This command dumps the data in the backup.dump
```

Then I saved backup.dump in my github account because the tutorials stated that in order to export data from local database to heroku, it must be at a location which can be retrieved using a http protocol. I did not understand why but I did what it said.

Then finally I ran this command:

```
heroku pg:backups restore "http://github.com/aditya9509/rubyOnRails/blob/master/backup.dump" DATABASE -a stark-beach-9626
```

The "stark-beach-9626 is the name of the app given by heroku.
After running this command, when I access the app, it shows "something went wrong". What am I missing here?

P.S. I am new to ruby on rails so please be as simple as you can when you answer. I have been busting my head to solve thi problem for hours now. Also, let me know if you need some additional info. I gave all the info I thought was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to restore the git blob and not the raw file, use `https://github.com/aditya9509/rubyOnRails/raw/master/backup.dump` for the url and it will work.